# Firefox not setting css style from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox

I need to respond to a hover over a table cell. This css code works fine:

```
#dialog-date-picker td { 
  border-style: outset !important;
  border : 2px solid #606060;
  cursor: pointer;
  ...etc
}

#dialog-date-picker td:hover {
  border-style: inset !important;
  border : 2px solid #6060b0;
}
```

However, I need a more complex hover response that I can't get in css, and I've started as follows:

```
$('#dialog-date-picker td').hover(function () {
      $(this).css('border-style', 'inset !important');
      $(this).css('border', '2px solid #6060b0');
   }, function() { 
      $(this).css('border-style', 'outset !important');
      $(this).css('border', '2px solid #606060');
   }
);
```

The jQuery equivalent works in Chrome and Opera, but not FF. Firebug shows that the code is executed, but nothing happens. Any ideas why this should be? Thanks.

### EDIT

Folks - I understand that this isn't elegant, and I should be using css and JS, and adding a class, but that's not the issue. I just took a working css solution and, as a first step, just put it in the JS above. At that point I found out that the JS equivalent worked in Opera and Chrome, but not FF. Combining the two css calls, and converting 'border-style' to 'borderStyle', didn't make a difference; it still doesn't work in FF.
Is it relevant that the dialog (jQuery UI) is dynamic? I've got a table within the dialog. Thanks for all the input.

### EDIT2

Simplified the code to:

```
$('#dialog-date-picker td').hover(
   function() { $(this).css('border', '2px inset  #6060b0 !important'); },
   function() { $(this).css('border', '2px outset #606060 !important'); }
);
```

with no change (works in IE8, Opera, Chrome, Safari, but not FF 3.6 or 8.0).

### EDIT3

Ok, given up on this. All the alternative (and better) stylesheet versions work in FF, so it seems a bit pointless worrying about why this particular code doesn't work in FF...

Comment: is "dialog-date-picker" id of table or tr or td ????

Comment: #dialog-date-picker is the id of a UI dialog, which contains a <td> as a descendant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because the second `css()` call is overwriting the first. Try this:

```
$('#dialog-date-picker td').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).css({
            'border-style': 'inset !important',
            'border': '2px solid #6060b0'
        });
    }, 
    function() { 
        $(this).css({
            'border-style': 'outset !important',
            'border': '2px solid #606060'
        });
    }
);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bDBWE/)

**EDIT**

Here's an extra fiddle thanks to PPvG and ptriek with a much more elegant solution which uses classes and solves the issue of setting an outset border, then immediately making it solid.

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XnQhH)

Comment: My answer was rubbish, this actually solves the problem. My might want to consider using CSS classes, though. Just use `$(this).addClass('hover')` and `$(this).removeClass('hover')` (or whatever class name you prefer) and declare the actual styles in CSS. That way, you don't have to edit your JavaScript if you ever want to change the styles.

Comment: why not just `'border': '2px inset #6060b0'`? it's a bit strange first setting border-style to inset, and after that changing it to solid...

Comment: Here's an updated example, using a class instead of hardcoded styles, as well as @ptriek's useful tip: http://jsfiddle.net/XnQhH/

Comment: maybe you'd better update your answer, since the actual answer is only in the comments now...

Comment: Combining into one hasn't made any difference to me - still works in Opera/Chrome, but not F/F. Your fiddle works in F/F, though, even after I've deleted the css section. I don't understand that.

Comment: @user785194 In which case you most likely have a CSS setting somewhere which still has a higher precedent that your `!important` one. Check the rules in place on the element in firebug see.

Comment: For the table data, Firbug is showing the non-hover settings as expected - it's picking up the right border-color and border-style. No idea how to find out what it's actually applying on hover, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $('#dialog-date-picker td').hover(function () {
      $(this).css({
         'border-style' : 'inset !important',
         'border'       : '2px solid #6060b0'
      });
   }, function() { 
      $(this).css({
         'border-style' : 'outset !important',
         'border'       : '2px solid #6060b0'
      });
   });
```

Thats also a little clean up in code for you too! Try not too use so many CSS functions, as your just essentially 're-dipping' when there's no reason too!

Also is your #dialog-date-picker being created by jQuery, if so you need to nest this function inside the function that creates that td.

Answer (score 0):

i guess the id `dialog-date-picker` is created `dynamically` so better to use `on` with events `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

```
$('#dialog-date-picker td').on('mouseover' :
    function () {
        $(this).css('border-style', 'inset !important');
        $(this).css('border', '2px solid #6060b0');
    }, 
    'mouseout' :function() { 
        $(this).css('border-style', 'outset !important');
        $(this).css('border', '2px solid #606060');

    }
);
```

Comment: You're right, it is created dynamically - it's a jQuery UI dialog. does this matter? Your answer doesn't actually make any difference, though - it works in Opera/Chrome, but not F/F. Note that I had to edit your code - I put an extra {} pair inside the `.on`.

Comment: Actually, this isn't quite right. `#dialog-date-picker` is the id of a static div in the html. The contents of the div are picked up by an SSI (`#include`), from the server. The contents are a table, hence `'#dialog-date-picker td'`. I think this means that the entire div is "static". However, the dialog is actually a jQueryUI dialog, and is popped up when a button is clicked. So does this make it dynamic? I think it's just made visible by the dialog UI.

Comment: I am not exactly getting you but if there is only one table then you neen give the id part, "$('td')" will do the work.

Answer (score 0):

You should preferably change both your CSS and JS and add a class to the TD on hover, and define this in your CSS. This reduces JS and keeps things where they belong:

http://jsfiddle.net/bDBWE/3/

```
$('#dialog-date-picker td').hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
}, function() { 
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery `css()` uses inline style sets to set the property.  The API it's using doesn't allow `!important` in the string.

See also https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=73941 for the WebKit bug on this; the existence of that bug (which they only recently fixed) is what allowed your script to work in Chrome and Safari.